# How to fix missing menus in non ubuntu maverick apps

Tags: gnome, filezilla

There's a bug with the menue of filezilla:

When opening filezilla there is no menu list. Very inconvenient because you can't open the "settings"-dialog. There are several workarounds that I tried - none of them really work.

1. change theme while filezilla is running, menu reapperars. Once you close and reopen it the menu is gone again.
2. add "export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0"
   " to .bashrc or just call it before starting filezilla. Doesn't have any effect for me - menu still missing.
3. tried "sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk" cause it's obviously to do with unity but the funny thing is even this method has no effect at all!

How can I fix this? How to do the troubleshooting? 
thx for reading, :p.

Comment: This needs to be filed as a bug against the upstream project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a wxWidgets bug and the affected apps are updating to work around the problem.

http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18444

If you've tried all the fixes mentioned in your question without a result, waiting for the latest version of these applications would seem to be your only option.

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

add "export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0" " to .bashrc or just call it before starting filezilla. Doesn't have any effect for me - menu still missing. might work if you added it to .profile instead of .bashrc

Comment: thx! But didn't work for me either.